Commuting powers of matrices
This is a very basic problem I encountered in research, but I couldn't find a straightforward answer online, so I thought I post this here. Let $A,B$ be PSD square matrices, then clearly $A^\theta$ and $B^\theta$ are defined for any real $\theta$. Is it true that $AB=BA$ implies $A^\theta B=BA^\theta$ for any real $\theta$?
It is well known that this holds for any positive integer. We can prove this for negative integers by just taking the inverse of both sides of the first equation and noting that the set of $\theta$ for which this holds is closed under addition. It is also pretty clear that we would only need to prove this for rational powers of $A$ by continuity, and by the same reason it is clear that it would suffice to prove this for $\theta = \frac 12$.
However, despite spending some time on this, I could not prove this, so I am guessing that I'm probably exhausted from a long day or it is false. In the latter case, can anyone come up with a counterexample?
Otherwise, can anyone come up with a proof? I know that this holds for $2 \times 2$ matrices already since for $A \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ PSD, $\sqrt A = aA+bI$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb R$, and both of those matrices commute with $B$.

Yes: they can be simultaneously diagonalized.

Oh... It's been a long day
